# nodejs print array elements all except first index

Tags: arrays, node.js, indexof

In NodeJS (latest), I'm able to print

```
console.log(args[0])
console.log(args[1])
console.log(args[2])
```

In my case, the function where I'm printing these arguments index variable is using NodeJS child.spawn(command,args) way i.e. a user can pass 1, 2 or 5 or N no. of arguments. As I don't know how many a user can set, I can't code the console.log() lines for that N no. of individual indexes.

How can I print all arguments except index args[0]?

Index args[1] contains the command name, which I'm able to print.
Index args[2] onwards, may contain args[2] = "-c", args[3]="param1", args[4]="paramX paramY" etc and so on depending upon how a user pushed arguments to args array in your .js file before calling the function which prints console.log lines.

I want to print the output like:
args[0]   = /usr/bin/bash
args[XXX] = -c, param1, param2, param3 param4, param5 etc, etc-etc

Comment: What you tried so far? Does args.forEach((el, i)=>{if(i != 0){console.log(el)}}) not enought?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo OP is trying to skip index 1, not 0.

Comment: @m-a-r-c-e-l-i-n-o little mistake, as he said the first element I doubted, that was corrected in the anwser.

Comment: Correct, I meant first element which should be [0], i'll fix the post

Comment: @ArunSangal Okay, I updated my post. Let me know if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for something along these lines:

```js
// wrap in function to mimic the arguments object
function execute() {

  // declare a place to store the arguments
  var result = []
  
  // iterate through each argument
  Array.from(arguments).forEach((value, key) => {
    // skip the second key
    if (key > 0) {
      // store each argument in the result array
      result.push(value)
    }
  })

  // console log the result array as multiple arguments
  console.log.apply(null, result) // -> /usr/bin/bash -c param1 param2 param3
}

// mock command
execute('/usr/bin/bash', 'command', '-c', 'param1', 'param2', 'param3')
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As I say in comments, something like this is what you may want.

```js
function func(...args){
  args.forEach((el, i)=>i != 1 && console.log(el));
};

func('/usr/bin/bash', 'Something not used', '-c', 'param1', 'param2', 'param3');
```

If you're using `arguments` variable:

```js
function func(){
  // Equivalent to [...arguments]
  Array.from(arguments).forEach((el, i)=>i != 1 && console.log(el));
};

func('/usr/bin/bash', 'Something not used', '-c', 'param1', 'param2', 'param3');
```